# How to get http response code w.r.t. a url in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to apply a if statement in template file based on response code with respect to a url. As I'm not aware of any direct method, I'm planning to make a custom template tag like:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='code')
def code(url):
    a = http.response(url)
    return a
```

I will then call this within the template as:

```
{% if model.fileurl|code==200 %}
<div>..............</div>
```

Also, is there any way to do it directly within the template as I'm trying to fill in the shoes of our django developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a template tag that returns the *status* code:

```
# app/templatetags/code.py

from django import template
from requests import get as reqget

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='code')
def code(url):
    reqget(url).status_code
```

The `app/templatetags/` directory need to contain an `__init__.py` file as well (if this is not the case yet, you can add an empty one).

and then in the template:

```
{% load code %}
{% if model.fileurl|code == 200 %}
<div>..............</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks... was looking for the same.Wanted to know about reqget.

Comment: @VishalQuery: it is just an alias for `requests.get(..)`: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Understood.. Missed the part where you imported get as reqget